# Using Django developers server is not displaying styles or favico

Tags: django

I seem to be having some sort of rendering problem possibly related to the free Django development server (manage.py runserver). I have a base.html that extends too my other files.  The Base file is using and external CSS file for formatting.  When the request is made to pull up a page the formatting defined in the CSS sheet is not showing on the page but all of the code from the base is properly extended to the file.  So to be clear I open up the source from the browser for a page that is not displaying the formatting.  I verify all of the code I expect to see is there extended from the base including the call to the css file.  Then I copy and paste from the "view source" window into into a new text file with an html extension and save in the same directory as the base.  Then, not using the server, I just open the file in a browser (double click it) and all of the formatting is there.  Same is true for the "favico" icon used in the address bar and tab area.  I can copy the text from the browser and save it and reopen not using the server and the icon is displayed...what am I doing wrong?

Also to be clear there is no error message just no formatting.  What gets displayed when running the server is the text for the page with no formatting...so the background is white not colored and there is no font formatting just default html formatting.

urls.py might be where my problem is.  This site is pulling the web page content out of a database and sending it to a generic html file which is then filled with the page contents.  The generic html file (view.html) is extended from the base and the base is formatted by an external CSS file.  So the pages don't actually exist independently.

In the views.py the way it works is basically based on 3 URLS, view, edit, save.

- If the URL does not exist then the views.py file calls on the
  edit.html which opens up a window with an entry area where I can add
  my code.  Then I hit the save button and all the text content that is
  actually HTML code is saved into the DB.
- If the page name does exist in the database then the contents for that page are extracted and sent to the View.html.

And again to be clear this is all working.  The browser feature to view source code displays all the info I want and I can copy and paste it into another file and it works.

Here are the URLS.PY relevant lines...

```
  url(r'^NWTACOL/page/(?P<page_name>[^/]*)/edit/$', 'NWTACOL.page.views.edit_page'),
  url(r'^NWTACOL/page/(?P<page_name>[^/]*)/save/$', 'NWTACOL.page.views.save_page'),
  url(r'^NWTACOL/page/(?P<page_name>[^/]*)/$', 'NWTACOL.page.views.view_page'),
```

Media URL setting is empty (I am still learning and I don't believe I have come across this setting yet in any of my trainings.  I will go read about that now)

```
MEDIA_URL = ''
```

The Link to my css file is

```
<link href="../Main_Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the relevant urls.py, your MEDIA_URL settings, and the <link> tag you're using to link to your css file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm also going to assume you're using Django 1.3 because new users very often get tripped up by the new staticfiles implementation:

First, specify both `STATIC_URL` and `STATIC_ROOT` in your `settings.py`. The usual way is:

```
import os.path

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

If all of your static resources are in "static" directories in one or more of you apps, you're done. Django will automatically serve these for you at `STATIC_URL` when `DEBUG=True`.

However, if you have another directory where you're storing static files (such as for CSS for a site-wide template, which doesn't just apply to one app). You must tell Django to treat these other directories as staticfiles directories:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'assets'),
)
```

I chose "assets" here because you **cannot** use the directory for `MEDIA_ROOT` (typically "site_media") for this. `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`, respectively, are only for uploads now.

Additionally, you **cannot** store your files in `STATIC_ROOT` either. This seems counter-intuitive, but `STATIC_ROOT` is simply the directory where Django stores the files when you run the `collectstatic` management command. It never actually serves files from here because that's something your production webserver should do.

So, to sum up, you likely need three directories for static resources:

1. A directory for user uploads (`MEDIA_ROOT`, usually "site_media")
2. A directory for `collectstatic` ('STATIC_ROOT`, usually "static")
3. A directory for project-wide static files (specify in
   `STATICFILES_DIRS`, call it anything you like)

Finally, you'll probably eventually get tripped up with serving admin media, as well. The setting for that is:

```
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL+'admin/'
```

Comment: Sorry but I am new to this, just learning and this is confusing to me.  I tried what you are saying but I am obviously doing it wrong.  So here is what I have in my project directory there is of course the pages DIR set up initially by the startapp function. Then I have an images DIR and an HTML DIR also at the same level in the project root not under the pages dir.   So first off can you have more than one thing in STATIC_ROOT?

Comment: Although the names of your directories do not *technically* matter, it's better to follow conventions, so there's a common frame of reference. Templates (your HTML) should go in a "templates" directory in your project root, with each app getting a directory the same as the app's inside that. (You can also have "templates" directories inside your apps). Images and other static resources should go into a containing folder (either "[project_root]/[app]/static/" or something like "[project_root]/assets/". You can then create folders for images, javscript, CSS, etc. inside those.

Comment: Okay so I will change to be consistent after I get it working because essentially I have it that way just different names.  I am taking a step back because if I can get the favico to work then the rest I can make work.  In any case how would I make that show up?  My settings.py has TEMPLAT_DIRS and STATICFILES_DIRS = ( "D:/web dev/NWTACOL/html",...) and in that directory I have all the HTML and the favico and in the base.html the link to the icon is <LINK rel=icon type=image/ico href="favicon.ico"/>

Comment: That's your problem right there. You need to use `STATIC_URL` in your template, i.e.: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}favicon.ico"/>`

Comment: ohh snap I had that earlier but removed it when trying to find a different typo...lets see if that works...nope still not showing up.

Comment: just to be clear I have STATIC_ROOT = "D:/web dev/NWTACOL/static"  : STATIC_URL = '/static/'  :  ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static/admin/'   :   STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    "D:/web dev/NWTACOL/html",
    "D:/web dev/NWTACOL/images",
    "D:/web dev/NWTACOL/assets",
    "D:/web dev/NWTACOL/templates",
)

Comment: Thanks Chris at least I know the right questions to ask now.  I will repost later with a better description of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the staticfiles app and Django 1.3? It *should* automatically serve css, js, image, etc, on the path: /static, if you have DEBUG = True. If not, you'll need to provide your own url pattern and view for serving static media.

Check out the dos at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: Yes I am running the most recent 1.3 version